# Async method does not return control flow to form

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have a problem with my async method in WPF application. I want to implement asynch await pattern in my WPF application to retain form responsiveness when querying database with EntityFramework. I did everything as described in microsoft examples but it doesn't return control flow to the application as example applications do.

Here is my button click code:

```
private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var loggedIn = await _gluUserRepository.LoginAsync(LoginTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text);

    Switcher.Switch(new Loader());
    if (loggedIn)
    {
        UserName = LoginTextBox.Text;
        Switcher.Switch(new Blank());
    }
    else
    {
        UserName = String.Empty;
        MessageBox.Show("Błędny login lub hasło. Spróbuj ponownie.");
        Switcher.Switch(new Login());
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginAsync method:

```
public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string login, string password)
{
    string hashedPassword = PasswordHasher.Hash(password);
    var user = await _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == login);
    if (user != null && user.Password == hashedPassword)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I've seen the same usage of async/await in Microsoft example applications, however, their WPF apps return control to Window handle, i.e. I can move window around when in my app that is impossible.

**What I want to achieve is using async/await pattern with WPF application to retain responsiveness of application. I want to display loading circle when querying database and return to method when querying has been completed.**

Anyone has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem you should post it as *an answer* not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. Though I don't know why it actually works. But it doesn't block UI thread. I don't think it's thread safe too, you should we weary.

```
private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var loginTask = userRepository.LoginAsync(LoginTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Password);
            controller.DisplayPageLoader();
            DbUser loginResult = await loginTask;
            if (loginResult != null)
            {
                controller.DisplayPageNewMeal();
                controller.SetLoggedUser(loginResult);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Błędny login lub hasło. Spróbuj ponownie.");
                controller.DisplayPageLogin();
            }
        }
```

and then in repository

```
public Task<DbUser> LoginAsync(string login, string password)
        {
            return Task.Run<DbUser>( () => Login(login, password));
        }

private DbUser Login(string login, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                string hashedPassword = PasswordHasher.Hash(password);
                var user = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == login);
                if (user.Result != null && user.Result.Password == hashedPassword)
                    return user.Result;
                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Blad logowania uzytkownika", ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly

```
 Switcher.Switch(new Loader());
```

is what shows the 'loading circle'.

You need to call it **before** you `await` the login. As it is now, your handler does everything else after `LoginAsync` returns.

You may also want to look at [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/). It provides a useful framework solving your problem.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly, however, I tried putting this before await and it still blocks main thread, I cannot move main window anywhere.

Comment: I suspect something else blocks or more likely bogs down UI thread making it unresponsive. What happens when you get rid of everything but the await call?

Comment: It still blocks, so I guess it's somewhere down under.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make guesses, but try changing the beginning of your `LoginButton_Click` code to start the task and `await` for its result later, like this:

```
private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var loggedInTask = _gluUserRepository.LoginAsync(LoginTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("before await");
    var loggedIn = await loggedInTask;
    MessageBox.Show("after await");

    // ...
}
```

You should be seeing two message boxes, one after another, both of them should be responsive, i.e. moveable and click-able. If you do see such behaviour, then the problem is most likely with your `Switcher.Switch` and has nothing to do with asynchronous methods of EntityFramework.

Answer (score 0):

i have main form with async load method :

private async   void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await _connection.Start();
            await _myHub.Invoke("Join");
            _myHub.On("recieved", data =>
            {
                var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

```
            messagewindows = new SendMessage(User, obj.Sender);


                 if ((obj.Reciever == User ) )
                 {
                    messagewindows. txtHistory.Text += obj.Sender + " :" + obj.text + Environment.NewLine;
                    messagewindows.Show();
                 }



        });

    }
```

i show second form for show message but form hang crash app :

private async void SendMessage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text = Reciever;

```
        await _connection.Start();
        await _myHub.Invoke("Join");



        _myHub.On("recieved", data =>
        {
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageSent>(data);
            if ((obj.Reciever == Sender || obj.Sender == Sender) && (obj.Sender == Reciever || obj.Reciever == Reciever))
            {


                    txtHistory.Text += obj.Sender + " :" + obj.text + Environment.NewLine;

                    txtHistory.SelectionStart = txtHistory.Text.Length;
                    txtHistory.ScrollToCaret();

            }
        });

    }
```